# Django Tasty Pie: serialization on PUT and POST methods

Tags: django, serialization, curl, tastypie

I'm building a RESTful app on Django and Tasty Pie. I have a problem with PUT and POST methods. When I do a request via Curl I have an error.

Curl requests:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type :application/json" -X POST -d '{"site_id":2,"post":2}' --user log:pass http://domain.com/core/api/v1/bookmarklet_post/

curl -i -H "Content-Type :application/json" -X PUT -d '{"site_id":2,"post":2}' --user log:pass http://domain.com/core/api/v1/bookmarklet_post/
```

The error:

```
{"error_message": "The format indicated 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' had no
available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`` on   
your Serializer.", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File    
\"/home/ilya/envs/rebelmouse/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 
178,  in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File  
\"/home/ilya/envs/rebelmouse/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 
379,  in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File  
\"/home/ilya/envs/rebelmouse/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 
409,  in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File  
\"/home/ilya/envs/rebelmouse/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 
1020,  in put_list\n    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data,  
format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))\n\n  File  
\"/home/ilya/envs/rebelmouse/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 
328,  in deserialize\n    deserialized = self._meta.serializer.deserialize(data,     
format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))\n\n  File  
\"/home/ilya/envs/rebelmouse/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/serializers.py\", line  
159, in deserialize\n    raise UnsupportedFormat(\"The format indicated '%s' had no  
available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`` on  
your Serializer.\" % format)\n\nUnsupportedFormat: The format indicated 'application/x-
www- form-urlencoded' had no available deserialization method. Please check your 
``formats`` and  ``content_types`` on your Serializer.\n"}
```

Serializer are implemented in my resource class:

```
class BookmarkletPostResource(Resource):
    site_id = fields.CharField(attribute='site_id')
    post = fields.CharField(attribute='post')    

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'bookmarklet_post'
        include_resource_uri = False
        limit = 10
        default_format = "application/json"
        object_class = ProxyStore
        authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = Serializer()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The content type header colons are misplaced.

It should look like this instead :  `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: use the type:"json" option when making the request. there's also a  .json method if i remember correctly